# redux-form mapStateToProps TypeError: Cannot read property 'values' of undefined even though i can console.log the state object and see the values

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, state, redux-form

So I'm using redux-form and I'm able to `console.log(state)` and see the  values out from the state object in `review.js` and see that they are preset in `state.form.PayForm.values.Dancer`, however if I try to reference that in the review page itself as a `console.log` directly I get the error described above. I have a very similar setup working perfectly on another project and haven't ever really had a problem with redux-form before.

Any help or insight in any direction would help. Thanks ahead of time for taking the time to look at this. Let me know if there is any other information I can supply.

Also for the sake of being easier on some people's eyes I took some screenshots of the code as well.

payform.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Field, reduxForm, reset } from 'redux-form'
import PayFormField from './PayFormField';


class PayForm extends Component{


  render(){
    return(
      <div>
        <label style={{color:'black'}}> Please select lead or follow 
        </label>
        <form onSubmit={this.props.handleSubmit(this.props.onFormSubmit)}>
          <Field type="text" component={PayFormField} name="Dancer" />
          <button style={{color:'black'}} type="submit">Review 
           Purchase
          </button>
       </form>
     </div>
    )
  }
}


export default reduxForm({
form:'PayForm',
destroyOnUnmount:false
})(PayForm)
```

payformfield.js

```
  import React, { Component } from 'react'
  import { Field } from 'redux-form';




  export default ({input,meta})=>{    
  return( 
    <div>
      <Field component="select" type="select" {...input} >
        <option 
        style={{color:'black'}}
        />
          <option value="Lead">Lead</option>
          <option value="Follow">Follow</option>
      </Field>  
    </div>
  )    
 }
```

payformholder.js

```
import React, {Component } from 'react';
import PayForm from './payForm'
import Review from './review'


class payFormHolder extends Component{
  state = { showreview: 'false'} 

  renderContent(){
    if(this.state.showreview=='true'){
      return(<Review />)
    }
    else{
      return(
        <PayForm 
        onFormSubmit={()=> this.setState({ showreview:'true' })}
      />
      )
    }
  }
  render(){
    return(
      <div>
        {this.renderContent()}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
export default payFormHolder;
```

review.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import {connect} from 'react-redux'

const Review = ({formValues}) => {
    return(
      <div> im the review 
        {formValues.values.Dancer} 
      </div>
    )
  }
function mapStateToProps(state){
  return{
    formValues: state.form.PayForm
  };
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Review)
```

just in case here in the packacge.json

```
  {
    "name": "salsanewyear",
    "version": "0.0.0",
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
      "start": "node ./bin/www & node apiServer.js"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
      "nodemon": "^1.17.5",
      "webpack": "^3.11.0"
    },
    "dependencies": {
      "axios": "^0.18.0",
      "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
      "babel-loader": "^7.1.4",
      "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
      "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
      "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
      "babel-preset-stage-1": "^6.24.1",
      "cookie-parser": "~1.4.3",
      "debug": "~2.6.9",
      "express": "~4.16.0",
      "http-errors": "~1.6.2",
      "http-proxy": "^1.17.0",
      "jade": "~1.11.0",
      "lodash": "^4.17.10",
      "morgan": "~1.9.0",
      "paypal-rest-sdk": "^1.8.1",
      "react": "^16.4.1",
      "react-bootstrap": "^0.32.1",
      "react-dom": "^16.4.1",
      "react-redux": "^5.0.7",
      "react-router": "^4.3.1",
      "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
      "redux": "^4.0.0",
      "redux-form": "^6.8.0",
      "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0"
    }
  }
```

client.js

```
  "use strict"
  import React from 'react';
  import {render} from 'react-dom';
  import {Provider} from 'react-redux';
  import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
  import ReduxThunk from 'redux-thunk'
  import reducers from './reducers/index';

  import LoadinPage from './components/LoadinPage';
  import Footer from './components/footer';




  const store = createStore(reducers, applyMiddleware(ReduxThunk));


  render(
    <Provider store={store}>
    <LoadinPage />
    </Provider>, document.getElementById("app"));
```

index.js(reducer)

```
  import {combineReducers} from 'redux';
  import { reducer as form } from 'redux-form';
  export default combineReducers({  form });
```

[payform.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lhDGL.png)

[payformfield.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WxxQ7.png)

[payformholder.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZF3HF.png)
[review.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ExPYc.png)

Comment: A little detail the key is `Values` and not `values`. i.e. `formValues.Values.Dancer` and not `formValues.values.Dancer`

Comment: oh that's just a typo it should say values

Comment: I [reproduced a sample application](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-p3q6p3) from the code you shared. I made a few adjustments. What does jump out to me is that you may not be [adding the `formReducer` to your store](https://redux-form.com/7.4.2/docs/gettingstarted.md/#step-1-of-4-form-reducer). Can you check to confirm this?

Comment: ive now added the client.js file and the reducer index to the main. if you need anythinng else let me know. and thanks for looking into it!

Answer (score 1):

At present, the form state is destroyed in the Redux store when the form is unmounted.

This is because there is a typo in the configuration object passed to the reduxForm HOC.

You want to set [destroyOnUnmount](https://redux-form.com/7.4.2/docs/api/reduxform.md/#-code-destroyonunmount-boolean-code-optional-) to be `false` and not <strike>`distroyOnUnmount`</strike> in the configuration object passed to reduxForm HOC.

Comment: I changed it and the state is still undefined. I'm also logging the props object inside the form as it's sent and it's coming back undefined before even unmounting.

Comment: I actually can't see anything wrong in your implementation ATM. What is printed to your console when you do `console.log(formValues)` in the component in `review.js`?

Comment: I'm not sure what changed however, today I'm able to log my values after deleted and reinstalling my node_modules. I don't see how this could have changed anything.